# Bug with nosetests? Adding a new case with autospec=True will take 15 seconds

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2013-March/005467.html

I posted this yesterday. I don't mean to rush and duplicate. But I want to resolve this as soon as possible. I will do test individual test modules meanwhile. Also, stackoverflow has more users than mailing list, in general.

Here is the repo:
https://bitbucket.org/yeukhon/bitbucket-python-api/src/18ddb36b9c7c7297398a6e97b889ddfc9b5e5ae8/tests/small?at=default

I have a base unit test class in `base.py`.  For `test_bitbucket.py`, I inherit
from the base unit test class.
I want to add new test cases and classes to `test_bitbucket.py` While doing
so, I discovered performance issue.

I ran `nosetests` inside tests/small and I am getting these mix results

```
Ran 18 tests in 14.523s        - autospec=True and test_account_creation
exists

Ran 18 tests in 0.621s         - autospec=False and test_account_creation exists


Ran 17 tests in 1.081s         - autospec=True and test_account_creation is
commented out

Ran 17 tests in 0.090s         - autospec=False, and test_account_creation
commented out
```

I understand requests is a big library, but the performance hit is crazy,
going from 1.1s to 14.5s with and without the new test class, respectively.

Interestingly, if we run `test_bitbucket.py` individually.

```
(bbpy)yeukhon at yeukhon-P5E-VM-DO:~/hg/bitbucket-python-api/tests/small$
nosetests test_bitbucket.py
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.090s

OK
```

Pretty much the same with/without autospec on.

Any idea? I don't know enough about nosetests internal.

Comment: What do you mean "autospec=True and test_account_creation exists"? Are you talking about whether autospec is used in base.UnittestBaseClass's setUpClass?  I didn't see test_account_creation in any of the files that you linked. What does it do?

Comment: @dbw Thanks for looking at it. I forgot to put the file. I updated the lunk above. Basically, I wanted to add a new test class. The new test case in that class is ``test_account_creation``. (I actually name it slightly differently). Following? I ran nosetests on all of them. It took 15 seconds. Wow. I commented that test case out, it was running about 1 second. Okay. That's what I meant when test_account_creation exist or deleted. I gave the results when `autospec=True/False` in the patch (see base.py), and results when the new test case `test_account_creation` was un/commented.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a guess because I don't know what your requests code does...

The [mock *autospec* argument](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#auto-speccing) is used to create a mock that has the same signature as the mocked object.  To set this up, [the create_autospec() function](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock.create_autospec) has to do some serious and recursive introspection of the object being replaced.  I would guess that this process is slow for your requests library.

The first thing to think about is why are you autospeccing?  Are you worried about calls to the mocked object not having the correct signature?  That's a reasonable thing to protect against, but I don't think that it is worth a 15s penalty!

Would it be feasible to only autospec part of requests? For example:

```
cls.req_pt = patch(cls.mod_name + '.requests')
cls.requests = cls.req_pt.start()

cls.rim_pt = patch(cls.mod_name + '.requests.really_important_method', autospec=True)
cls.rim = cls.req_pt.start()
```

Another thing to try would be setting `instance=True` in the patch constructor:

```
cls.req_pt = patch(cls.mod_name + '.requests', autospec=True, instance=True)
cls.requests = cls.req_pt.start()
```

From my reading of mock.py, it looks like this should limit recursive calls to create_autospec().  It **will** change the behavior of the mock, of course, so I'd test it carefully to make sure that it does what you expect.

Comment: thanks for replying here and on the TIP mailing list. That didn't work out. But I will take your suggestion and mock specific things. I will get back to you later. Thanks!